# How to use convex metric space definition

Tags: analysis

[image]

How to show that x is convex metric space?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! You could put the image directly in the question. Plus, if you provide any thoughts, more people are willing to help.

Comment: @YujieZha:  I think the OP doesn't have enough reputation to post images yet, but we might review the image for suitability and [consider an edit to make it visible](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23224/guidelines-for-making-images-visible).  Better would be to transcribe the image into $\LaTeX$ if there is a desire to answer this Question.

Comment: @hardmath Sure, I've embedded the picture.

Comment: @YujieZha:  I suspect the "image" contains an error in its definition of mapping $W$.  The signature $W: X^2 \times [0,1]^2 \to X$ does not match the expression shown for $W(x,y,\alpha)$ because $\alpha$ there ought to be a single scalar (not a pair of scalars).  It appears the importance of $W$ is for defining how one takes a "convex combination" of $x,y \in X$.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that $X$ is a convex set.

Let $t \in (0,1)$ and $(x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2) \in X$

$$tx_1+(1-t)y_1>0$$ $$tx_2+(1-t)y_2>0$$ thus $$t(x_1,x_2)+(1-t)(y_1,y_2) \in X$$

But  $X$ is not a metric space because $d(x,y)$ is not a metric.

Take $x=(1,2)$ and $y=(2,1)$

We have that $x,y \in X $ and $d(x,y)=0$, but $x \neq y$.

So the first axiom of the metric is not satisfied.